# New to Git. Made a big mistake with git commit and ended up at an older commit

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and I've made a huge mistake. Git kept prompting me with

`git - rejected master -> master (non-fast-forward)`.

But, I still committed by using:

`--force`

This was disastrous, the whole project changed back to the stage it was at about a week ago. I've lost so many changes. I seem to have been pushed back to an earlier commit. Is there anyway I can get back to one of my newer commits? As I have made an enormous amount of changes and need to get them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git reflog` command. The reflog command will give you a good history of what's been happening on the head of your branches. Run it, then find the line that refers to the state that you want to get back to.

Once you found the commit, reset your branch to point to the specific commit.

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

The `--hard` options sets the HEAD of the current branch back to the commit that you specify.

Comment: @RamarioDepass You are welcome. Pls accept the answer (click the check mark next to the answer), it lets everyone know your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears you did a `git push --force`. This is very bad.
I am not sure if this will work but it is worth a try. Go in order of suggestions and only if one suggestion doesn't work skip to the next one:

- Try reverting the commit hash that you forced onto the `master` branch with `git revert {commit_hash}`. If you feel your changes have been restored then do another `git commit` and `git push`.
- If the above did not work and this was the last commit you did you can try to go back one commit with `git checkout HEAD~1`. This will take the HEAD back one commit. The easiest way to know how many commits you need to go back is using `git reflog` and see which commit was the last stable one. If this state is what you feel is correct then do a `git commit` and `git push`.

Please don't ignore git warnings. In my experience git only warns you about the absolutely necessary stuff.

Comment: 1.`git revert {commit_hash}` would revert the changes made in the particular commit. But that's not what he want.

Comment: @KarthikBose I had that doubt but I felt it was worth a try.

Comment: And 2. `git checkout HEAD~1` would checkout the parent of the current commit, not the previous commit.